# How to validate admin config options for Magento module

Tags: magento

I am trying to create a magento module. This module has two config options in the admin menu .i.e, "Enabled" and "api_key". I want to check and throw and error for "api_key" option only if the "Enabled" options is set to 1. I am using backend module but unable to get the "enabled" option passed to the server when updating. The getstoreConig always returns the value in database not the current one.
Regards,
Vijay

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Magneto setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `Observer` on event `admin_system_config_changed_section_{yoursection}`, as stated by this answer:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3014 (credit to [Fabian Blechschmidt](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/217/fabian-blechschmidt))